# Calculate last point in triangle

Tags: triangulation

I'm trying to find the last point in a triangle like this below
[image]

I know what $X1,Y1$ and $X2,Y2$ is. Now i need to Find $X3,Y3$ which should lay at a angle of $45°$ from $X2,Y2$

I can get the length between $X1Y1$ And $X2,Y2$ If needed.

I know this should be a simple matter, but i just can't find the right way to do it. And by searching online, i only found some high level math, i could not follow. So please bare with me, an explain how this can be done, for stupid me.

Comment: The length between $(X_1,Y_1)$ and $(X_2,Y_2)$ is equal to the length between $(X_1,Y_1)$ and $(X_3,Y_3)$. And you mean at an angle of $45^o$ from $(X_1,Y_1)$ not $(X_2,Y_2)$.

Comment: As you can see, i'm not good ad math. 
but with this, i still don't know how to find the last point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using complex numbers**

\begin{align*}
  \frac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1} &= \operatorname{cis} \frac{\pi}{4} \\
  &= \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}} \\
  z_3 &= z_1+\frac{(1+i)(z_2-z_1)}{\sqrt{2}} \\
  x_3+y_3 i &= x_1+y_1 i+\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}} [(x_2-x_1)+(y_2-y_1)i] \\
  &= \left( x_1+\frac{x_2-x_1+y_1-y_2}{\sqrt{2}} \right)+
     \left( y_1+\frac{x_2-x_1+y_2-y_1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)i \\
  \begin{pmatrix} x_3 \\ y_3 \end{pmatrix} &=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    x_1+\frac{x_2-x_1+y_1-y_2}{\sqrt{2}} \\
    y_1+\frac{x_2-x_1+y_2-y_1}{\sqrt{2}}
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

**Only with elementary backgrounds**

> Let $A=(x_1,y_1)$, $B=(x_2,y_2)$, then
>
> $$C=(x_2+y_1-y_2 ,\, y_2+x_2-x_1)$$
>
> Note that $$AD : DC = 1: \sqrt{2}-1$$
>
> By section formula
>
> \begin{align*}
>     D &= \frac{C+(\sqrt{2}-1)A}{1+(\sqrt{2}-1)} \\
>     &= \frac{(x_2+y_1-y_2 ,\, y_2+x_2-x_1)+(\sqrt{2}-1)(x_1 ,\, y_1)}
>             {\sqrt{2}} \\
>     (x_3, y_3)
>     &= \left(
>          x_1+\frac{x_2-x_1+y_1-y_2}{\sqrt{2}} ,\,
>          y_1+\frac{x_2-x_1+y_2-y_1}{\sqrt{2}}
>        \right)
>   \end{align*}

[image]

Comment: I'm sure this is awesome, But as I said, I'm very stupid at math, So I kinda don't get what is going on here.

Comment: Rotate from $(x_2,y_2)$ by $45^{\circ}$ anti-clockwise about $(x_1,y_1)$, you reach $(x_3,y_3)$.

Comment: Sry, i didnt explain myself properly, I can't read the formular, is like a other language. I do understand that if i can rotate it 45 degree, it would be at that point. but can't understand the formular for doing the math

Comment: Have you learnt complex numbers (that involving $\sqrt{-1}$)?  If not, how about matrix algebra?

Comment: To some point. But what is i, And what is cis? that i do not know.
I think what i'm missing here is a step by step explanation of what this formular do

Comment: $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and $\operatorname{cis} \theta=\cos \theta+i\sin \theta$

Comment: This is what i need, Now i understand, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
1968054
```

$x_3=x_1+\frac{(x_2+y_1-x_1-y_2)\sqrt2}2$
$y_3=y_1+\frac{(x_2+y_2-x_1-y_1)\sqrt2}2$

I derived these from the following formulæ:
$\left\{\begin{matrix}
X=\frac{(x_2-x_1)(x-x_1)+(y_2-y_1)(y-y_1)}{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}\\
Y=\frac{-(y_2-y_1)(x-x_1)+(x_2-x_1)(y-y_1)}{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}
\end{matrix}\right.$
These map $(x_1\mid y_1)\text{ onto }(0\mid 0)\text{, }$
$(x_2\mid y_2)\text{ onto }(1\mid 0)\text{ and other points accordingly.}$

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x=(x_2-x_1)X-(y_2-y_1)Y+x_1\\
y=(y_2-y_1)X+(x_2-x_1)Y+y_1
\end{matrix}\right.$
These reverse the mapping.

Comment: Will you share of what significance is the highlighted 7-digit number?

Comment: @amWhy \ Gladly! That's the number that MathSE assigned to the question. I include it with my answer just to keep my mind straight, particularly when I intend to return to the question repeatedly until I am satisfied.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes sense to do!  Thanks for sharing!